# Suma de productos

Tags: mysql, sql

El problema que no me deja dormir es este:
Tengo una tabla de productos:

tabla **GENERAL**:

```
                            ID  || PRODUCT  || SECTION
                           1024 || 1/4 Poly || hoses
                           1025 || 3/8 Poly || hoses
                           1026 || 1/2 Poly || hoses
```

Y tengo otra tabla donde se registra la salida y entrada de cada producto:

tabla **ENTRANCE**:

```
                              ID  ||     DATE   || QTY
                             1024 || 01-01-2020 || -5
                             1024 || 02-01-2020 || -2
                             1025 || 05-01-2020 || -8
                             1025 || 07-01-2020 || 20
```

Lo que necesito es una consulta SQL que me permita saber la cantidad existente de cada producto segun la seccion (en este caso de la seccion hoses). Por ejemplo:

```
                      ID ||  PRODUCT || QTY || SECTION
                    1024 || 1/4 poly || -7  || hoses
                    1025 || 3/8 poly || 12  || hoses
                    1026 || 1/2 poly || 0   || hoses
```

Espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro y que me puedan ayudar con esto. Gracias.

Comment: Como sugerencia, procura siempre indicar qué has intentado para resolver tu problema. Las preguntas sin código a veces se asimilan como _poco esfuerzo de quien pregunta_. Espero que alguna de las respuestas te ayude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, tenés que hacer un **inner join** de las dos tablas para relacionarlas, después sumas las qty con **sum**, **where** para filtrar las section y por último un **group by** para agrupar y evitar duplicados.

```
SELECT g.id, g.product, sum(e.qty) as total, e.section
    FROM general as g
    INNER JOIN entrance as e
     ON g.id = e.id
    WHERE g.section = 'hoses'
    GROUP BY g.id, g.product, e.section
```

Saludos!

Comment: Imagino falta g.product, e.section en la cláusula Group By?

Answer (score 0):

Con el contenido que se ve de las tablas GENERAL y ENTRANCE, si quieres conseguir el resultado que muestras, donde también aparece el id 1026, yo probaría con un LEFT JOIN.
De esa forma, el id 1026 se mostraría con resultado 'null' en el campo QTY, ya que al no estar en la tabla ENTRANCE, con un INNER JOIN no aparecería.

```
SELECT g.id, g.product, SUM(e.qty) QTY, g.section
FROM GENERAL as g
LEFT JOIN ENTRANCE as e
ON g.id = e.id
WHERE g.section = 'hoses'
GROUP BY g.id;
```